# Get the coordinates vector of a basis in $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine if $V$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^4$. If the answer is possitive, then give the coordinate vector in this basis.

$V=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 4 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$

So(...)

Putting this columns together:
$\require{extpfeil}\Newextarrow{\xRightarrow}{5,5}{0x21D2}$
$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  2 & 1 & 4 \\
  3 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\xRightarrow[\text{by row reduction}]{}
A_R=
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

a) Linear independence

Let $C \in \Bbb R^3$

$A_R \times C = 0 \implies c_1=c_2=c_3 = 0$

Then $V$ is linearly independent.

b) $V$ generates $\Bbb R^4$

Let $K \in \Bbb R^3, X \in \Bbb R^4$

$A \times K  = X \implies \begin{cases} k_1 + k_3 = a \\ k_2+k_3=b \\ 2k_1+k_2+4k_3 = c\\ 3k_1 +k_2 + 4k_3 = d\end{cases}$

then $\mathrm{gen}[V] = \Bbb R^4$

Therefore, by a) and b), $V$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$

But, how can I get the coordinate vector in this basis?

If this is wrong, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: $V$ only contains $3$ vectors and any basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ must have $4$.

Comment: in particular, span(V) wont equal r4

Comment: if $\dim(V) < \dim(W) \implies V$ is not a basis for $W$?

Comment: Correct. $\ \ \ $

Comment: Do you have any proof of thhat proposition?

Comment: Try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) as well as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Examples).

Comment: any number of vectors in V greater than 4 are linearly dependant, any number of vectors in V less than 4 cannot span

Answer (score 1):

> if $\dim(V) < \dim(W) \implies V$ is not a basis for $W$?

Correct.

That would mean that $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$.

That is, here: $\dim (\Bbb R^4) \not = 3$

The mistake is, as already said, that $\mathrm{span}(V)=\Bbb R^4$.

Take $(0,0,0,1)$ which belongs to $\Bbb R^4$. Can you write it as a linear combination of $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)$?

Comment: the fact that $\dim (V) < \dim (W)$ is because if take the echelon form for the matrix formed taking the vector on $V$, it always will have a null row?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The thing is that, if V is a basis for W, just like John Habert mentioned, the definition of dimension implies that we would have that dimW equals the cardinality of V. Check, as already said, the definitions of basis and dimension.